Why are embedded subtitles lost when repairing video with FFmpeg?
When I run the following command on a video file, I lose the embedded subtitles.
ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy OUTPUT.mp4

Do I need to add something here, so I don't lose the subtitles if present?
I normally run this command on my files before playing on my Roku Media Player.

How many subtitles do you have? I runned some tests here and this method you used seem to remove all but the first subtitle, if you have 3 you end up with 1 and if you have 1 it keeps that one subtitle. Can you confim?

I just had one subtitle embedded and it was removed.

Hmm, maybe that is because your input file is mp4 and my tests where on a mkv file....

If you add -map 0 to the command it seems to keep all tracks including the subtitles:
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.mkv

